# How to create a function to convert a number into binary form using recursion assuming it is a positive int

Tags: python, recursion, binary

My code runs correctly but there is an extra 0 out front how do I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: You should edit this question and include the code in the question itself rather than an image of the code. If you indent the lines of code four spaces it will format it as code.

Comment: I can't see half of the code! do what @MarkMeyer Said in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag as an optional parameter to indicate whether or not the call is at the top level, and if and only if so, it would return `'0'`; otherwise it would return an empty string:

```
def binary(n, top_level=True):
    if n > 0:
        return binary(n // 2, False) + str(n % 2)
    elif top_level:
        return '0'
    else:
        return ''
```

so that:

```
binary(11)
```

returns: `'1011'`